# Image is not getting displayed from Kivy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Here is the code along with the kv file.

The image is not getting displayed based on the spinner selection.

I need to display the image in the second screen with two-three images and on clicking the same, should give a popup with details and another image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image  
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import SlideTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True) 

kv=Builder.load_string("""
<Image1n>: 
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout: 
        padding:5
        ImageButton: 
            source: 'anorth.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .8}
            on_release: root.on_press()
    BoxLayout: 
        padding:5
        ImageButton: 
            source:'bnorth.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .2}
            on_release: root.on_press()
<Image1e>: 
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout: 
        padding:5
        ImageButton: 
            source: 'aeast.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .8}
            on_release: root.on_press1()
    BoxLayout: 
        padding:5
        ImageButton: 
            source:'beast.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .2}
            on_release: root.on_press1()
"""
)
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):  
    pass
class Image1n(Screen,BoxLayout):
    pass
class Image1e(Screen,BoxLayout):
    pass
class Image1BHKNorth(Screen,ButtonBehavior, Image,GridLayout):
    def imagebutton1bhknorth(self):
        return kv
    def on_press(self):        
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=2) 
        popupLabel = Label(text = "         Details"
                           "\n House Type - 1BHK"
                           "\n Area - 800")
        image= Image(source='anorth1.jpg')
        closeButton = Button(text = "Close",size_hint_x=0.1,size_hint_y=0.1)  
        layout.add_widget(popupLabel) 
        layout.add_widget(image)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)
        popup = Popup(title ='                        Details', 
                      content = layout)   
        popup.open()    
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)    
class Image1BHKEast(Screen,ButtonBehavior, Image,GridLayout):
    def imagebutton1bhkeast(self):
        return kv
    def on_press1(self):        
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=2) 
        popupLabel = Label(text = "         Details"
                           "\n House Type - 1BHK"
                           "\n Area - 800\n Direction - North")
        image= Image(source='aeast1.jpg')
        closeButton = Button(text = "Close",size_hint_x=0.1,size_hint_y=0.1)  
        layout.add_widget(popupLabel) 
        layout.add_widget(image)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)
        popup = Popup(title ='                        Details', 
                      content = layout)   
        popup.open()    
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.spinnerObject = Spinner(text ="House", 
              values =("1BHK", "2BHK", "3BHK"), 
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))  

        self.spinnerObject.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2) 

        self.spinnerObject.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.40}
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection)
        self.spinnerSelection.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}
        #second spinner
        self.spinnerObject1 = Spinner(text ="Area", 
              values =("800","1200", "1500", "1800", "2200"), 
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))  
        self.spinnerObject1.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2) 

        self.spinnerObject1.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.40} 

        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject1)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject1.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection1 = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject1.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection1)
        self.spinnerSelection1.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}
        #third spinner
        self.spinnerObject2 = Spinner(text ="Directions", 
              values =("North","East"), 
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))  
        self.spinnerObject2.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2)       
        self.spinnerObject2.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.20}       
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject2)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject2.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection2 = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject2.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection2)
        self.spinnerSelection2.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}

        layout.add_widget(Label(text=self.name, font_size=30))
        navig = BoxLayout(size_hint=(0.2,0.4),pos_hint={'top': 1, 'center_x':0.5})
        next = Button(text='Search')
        next.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)
        navig.add_widget(next)
        layout.add_widget(navig)
        self.add_widget(layout)
    def spinner_select(self,spinner,text):
        self.spinnerSelection.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject.text
        self.spinnerSelection1.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject1.text
        self.spinnerSelection2.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject2.text

        self.ib=Image1BHKNorth()
        self.ib1=Image1BHKEast()
        if self.spinnerSelection.text=='1BHK'and self.spinnerSelection1.text=='800' and self.spinnerSelection2.text=='North':
            self.ib.imagebutton1bhknorth()
            sm.add_widget(Image1BHKNorth(name='onebhkn'))
        if self.spinnerSelection.text=='1BHK'and self.spinnerSelection1.text=='800' and self.spinnerSelection2.text=='East':
            self.ib1.imagebutton1bhkeast()
            sm.add_widget(Image1BHKEast(name='onebhke'))


    def switch_next(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(CustomScreen())

class SA(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SA().run()
```

**REVISED:**

The conditions are working properly as the popup shows the conditioned image. The only problem is that the images in the kv file(expected to display two images vertically) is not getting displayed(only a blank screen is what I get). The popup image is getting displayed perfectly along with the content given.

Comment: Could you please add an structure example of your project? Just to check out where are those images you're trying to show ^^

Comment: @JorgeC.M I'm actually using Anaconda spyder as the IDE and have saved the images in the folder where my code is getting saved. The image is getting displayed when no conditions are given.

Comment: I see... could you please check (print) values of spinners' text after `self.spinnerSelection.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject.text`lines? Maybe text values are not the same as the ones you check and then it doesn't enter at if clauses

Comment: @JorgeC.M The text in the spinner which is selected,is getting displayed correctly ```self.spinnerSelection.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject.text``` for this line of code. May be there is some other logical error because the layout is getting displayed at the corner and on clicking, it gives a popup too.

Comment: Some serious problems with your code. First, your 'kv' string is effectively not used. You reference it in your code, but you don't actually do anything with it. You are doing some risky multiple inheritance in your `Image1n`, `Image1e`, `Image1BHKNorth`, and `Image1BHKEast` classes. In each of those classes your are extending the `Screen` class (which itself extends `RelativeLayout`) as well as another `Layout` class (`GridLayout` or `BoxLayout`). All three of those `Layout` classes have their own `do_layout()` method. Which one are you expecting to be used?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I wanted the images to get displayed in a BoxLayout and wanted to use it along with the screen manager. Did you mean that I shouldn't be using BoxLayout along with Screen class? I was unaware about Screen class extending other layout classes.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Is there any suggestion? I'm new to Kivy framework and couldn't find where the mistake is.I tried making changes in the classes and there is no change in th output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that I think will do what you want. I have added numerous comments in the code to explain the changes I made.

I noticed that in several places you were doing multiple inheritance (and some were conflicting). You should only do subclassing when you need your subclass to be an instance of the super class. Like your `ImageButton` is an `Image` that has `ButtonBehavior`. But whenever you think about extending a class, consider whether it might be better to just include an instance of that class in yours. For example your `Image1BHKNorth` extends `Image`, but is that really needed? You don't need to extend `Image` in order to use an `Image` instance in your class.

```
# any changes to Config should be the first thing done!!!
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import SlideTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder

# use Builder.load_string() to tell Kivy about your rules for building Widgets
Builder.load_string("""
# A rule that says how a Image1BHKEast Widget should be built
<Image1BHKEast>:
    Image1e:          # Image1e is just a BoxLayout, so this could be replaced by simply BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        orientation:'vertical'
        ImageButton: 
            source: 'anorth.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True    # allows the image to be stretched to fill the specified size
            keep_ratio: True       # keeps the aspect ratio of the image constant, to avoid distortion
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .8}  # odd positioning (the left side of the image will likely be off screen)
            on_release: root.on_press1()
        ImageButton: 
            source:'bnorth.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .2}
            on_release: root.on_press1()

# similar rule for Image1BHKNorth
<Image1BHKNorth>:
    Image1n:
        padding:5
        orientation:'vertical'
        ImageButton: 
            source: 'aeast.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .8}
            on_release: root.on_press()
        ImageButton: 
            source:'beast.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .2}
            on_release: root.on_press()
"""
)
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

# The two classes below extended Screen, but were never used as Screen
# They now only extend BoxLayout
# If there is no additional behavior required of these classes, they can be eliminated completely
class Image1n(BoxLayout):
    pass
class Image1e(BoxLayout):
    pass

# Eliminated uneeded parent classes
# When extending Behavior classes, The Behavior class must be listed first
# eliminated the imagebutton1bhknorth() method as it provided no useful functionality
class Image1BHKNorth(ButtonBehavior, Screen):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.size)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=2)
        popupLabel = Label(text = "         Details"
                           "\n House Type - 1BHK"
                           "\n Area - 800")
        image= Image(source='anorth1.jpg')
        closeButton = Button(text = "Close",size_hint_x=0.1,size_hint_y=0.1)
        layout.add_widget(popupLabel)
        layout.add_widget(image)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)
        popup = Popup(title ='                        Details',
                      content = layout)
        popup.open()
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

# same comments as above
class Image1BHKEast(ButtonBehavior, Screen):
    def on_press1(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=2)
        popupLabel = Label(text = "         Details"
                           "\n House Type - 1BHK"
                           "\n Area - 800\n Direction - North")
        image= Image(source='aeast1.jpg')
        closeButton = Button(text = "Close",size_hint_x=0.1,size_hint_y=0.1)
        layout.add_widget(popupLabel)
        layout.add_widget(image)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)
        popup = Popup(title ='                        Details',
                      content = layout)
        popup.open()
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.spinnerObject = Spinner(text ="House",
              values =("1BHK", "2BHK", "3BHK"),
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))

        self.spinnerObject.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2)

        self.spinnerObject.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.40}
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection)
        self.spinnerSelection.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}
        #second spinner
        self.spinnerObject1 = Spinner(text ="Area",
              values =("800","1200", "1500", "1800", "2200"),
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))
        self.spinnerObject1.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2)

        self.spinnerObject1.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.40}

        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject1)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject1.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection1 = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject1.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection1)
        self.spinnerSelection1.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}
        #third spinner
        self.spinnerObject2 = Spinner(text ="Directions",
              values =("North","East"),
              background_color =(0.784, 0.443, 0.216, 1))
        self.spinnerObject2.size_hint = (0.2, 0.2)
        self.spinnerObject2.pos_hint ={'x': .35, 'y':.20}
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject2)
        #spinner-selection
        self.spinnerObject2.bind(text=self.spinner_select)
        self.spinnerSelection2 = Label(text="%s"%self.spinnerObject2.text)
        layout.add_widget(self.spinnerSelection2)
        self.spinnerSelection2.pos_hint={'x': .1, 'y':.3}

        layout.add_widget(Label(text=self.name, font_size=30))
        navig = BoxLayout(size_hint=(0.2,0.4),pos_hint={'top': 1, 'center_x':0.5})
        next = Button(text='Search')
        next.bind(on_release=self.switch_next)
        navig.add_widget(next)
        layout.add_widget(navig)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def spinner_select(self,spinner,text):
        self.spinnerSelection.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject.text
        self.spinnerSelection1.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject1.text
        self.spinnerSelection2.text = "%s"%self.spinnerObject2.text

        # Eliminated ineffective Widget creation and method calls
        if self.spinnerSelection.text=='1BHK'and self.spinnerSelection1.text=='800' and self.spinnerSelection2.text=='North':
            sm.add_widget(Image1BHKNorth(name='onebhkn'))
        if self.spinnerSelection.text=='1BHK'and self.spinnerSelection1.text=='800' and self.spinnerSelection2.text=='East':
            sm.add_widget(Image1BHKEast(name='onebhke'))


    def switch_next(self, *args):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='main'))    # All Screens need a name

class SA(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SA().run()
```